# First order logic (Every case problem)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

Every student in the class has visited Africa or America

student(x): x is student in the class.

Africa(x) : x has visited Africa.

America(x) : x has visited America.

Domain of x is people in the world

a.) ∀(x)[student(x) ⟹ (Africa(x) V America(x)) ]

b.) ∀(x)[student(x) ∧ (Africa(x) V America(x)) ]

Do these both statement gives same answer and which one is better.(why?)

statement a) is what I see in book and statement b) is what I think can also give same answer as a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement (a) also claims that every person in the world is a student (since the statement $\forall x: \mathrm{student}(x)$ follows directly from it), which is not true.

For example, take the set $\mathcal D=\{\text{Joe}, \text{Mary}\}$ in which  $\text{Joe}$ is a student who has visited Africa and Mary is a newborn child who visited no continent but Europe where she was born.

Then, statement (a) is true for this domain, but statement (b) is not true for this domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot especially for your example and explanation too.

Comment: if domain of x is student only then I think statement (a) == statement (b)

Comment: @codenut Sure, but in that case, the statements are equivalent to $\forall x(\text{Africa}(x)\lor\text{America}(x))$.

Comment: Just one thought on your example what if your set  D ={Mary} which same condition now  statement (a) is true, but i think it needs to be false.

Comment: @codenut sure, but that's not my example any more